# Site Collection +New button options not available after applying site template (SiteDesign/SiteScript)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, site-template, json, site-script

Hello and thank you in advance. I have deployed the following site design script below. However, once i apply the template the options under +New on the site collection homepage are no longer available as seen in the screenshot. Any ideas how i can add these back in so the user experience is the same as before applying the template?
[image]

```
{

    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/site-design-script-actions.schema.json",

    "actions": [

          {
            "verb": "setSiteExternalSharingCapability",
            "capability": "Disabled"
          },

{
  "verb": "joinHubSite",
  "hubSiteId": "0269fb1d-7079-4476-9cc7-5c094d1101f2"
},

        {

        "verb": "triggerFlow",

        "url": "https://prod-187.westus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/0515f7d85d084d619a4daecae7c3e495/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=8IjyKPmd55kzHwIz4RN8MlQ3vOmmbWqx6YS6tfqq40Q",

        "name": "Apply a site template",

        "parameters": {

            "event": "Microsoft Event",

            "product": "SharePoint"

        }

        }

    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a template to an existing site, your content will not automatically merge with the new template. Instead, a new default home page will be created along with other new content. If you want to restore the "+New" button options, you might need to customize your site script or apply a different site template that includes these options.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, upon further research, there is no option to restore the default options via site script or powerautomate. Instead, a quick fix (which is manually done), is to set a different site page as the default homepage, then set your home.aspx back to the default homepage. I've confirmed this works. Thanks